# Hangman assistance. I need the game to stop when the user uses up all his tries or when he guesses all the letters in the word

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you stop a game of Hangman when the user guesses all the right letters or if the user uses all his tries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8290936/how-do-you-stop-a-game-of-hangman-when-the-user-guesses-all-the-right-letters-or)

I can basically do all the other things needed to make a basic hangman game except to stop the game when the user uses up all his tries and when the user guesses all the letters in the word. Also another problem is that when i input 3 tries or whatever i can guess as many times as i want whether the guess was right or wrong.  I have used different methods in order to make it more clean and have more style.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Hangman {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String[] dictionary = loadWords();
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Hangman!");
        System.out.println("How many tries");
        int tries = kb.nextInt();

        String word = chooseWord(dictionary);
        System.out.println("OK, I've choseen my word. Start guessing");
        System.out.println(word);
        boolean[] bool = new boolean[26];



        while (tries >=  0){
        String wordguess = kb.next();
            char guess = wordguess.charAt(0);
            processGuess(guess, word, bool);
            printPattern(word, bool);
        }


        // FINISH IMPLEMENTING THIS!
    }


    // Loads a list of words from a file and returns the lsit as a String[].
    // DO NOT ALTER THIS IMPLEMENTATION!!
    public static String[] loadWords() throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner wordFile = new Scanner(new File("dictionary.txt"));
        String line;
        while (wordFile.hasNextLine()) {
            line = wordFile.nextLine();
            if(!line.equals(""))   
                wordList.add(line);
        }

        String[] result = new String[1];
        return wordList.toArray(result);
    }
    // Takes an array of strings that represents the valid words as a parameter.
    // Chooses one such word randomly and returns it.
    public static String chooseWord(String[] dict) {

        Random r = new Random();
        int numword = r.nextInt(dict.length); 
        String hangword = dict[numword];  
        return hangword;

    }

    // Checks if a player has won the game
    // Returns true only if all letters in the word have been guessed
    public static boolean hasWon(String word, boolean[] guesses) {
        int incorrect_tries = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (guesses[word.charAt(i)-'a'] == false){
                incorrect_tries++;
                return false;
                }
            }   
            return true;

            }


    // Prints out the pattern of letters in the secret word based on the word 
    //    and the letters that have been guessed.
    // Prints any letter that has already been guessed and a _ for a letter that 
    //    has not been guessed.
    public static void printPattern(String word, boolean[] guesses) {
        StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) { 
            if (guesses[word.charAt(i) - 'a']) { 
                pattern.append(word.charAt(i));
            }
            else {
                pattern.append("_");
            }
            pattern.append(" ");
            }

        System.out.println(pattern.toString());
    }



    // Handles a guess by marking the letter as guessed and returns the number of 
    //    tries to be charged: 0 if the guessed letter is in the word and 1 otherwise. 
    public static int processGuess(char guess, String word, boolean[] guesses) {        


        if(guesses[(guess - 'a')] == false){
            guesses[(guess - 'a')] = true;
}
    else {
        System.out.println("you already guessed that letter");


    }
        return guess;
}

}
```

Comment: Sorry i know Im just so desperate for help because all the advice the people have given me haven't really worked. I've been working on this code for days and its due tomorrow I just need help please can you guys help me please. I'm begging

Comment: voting to close? what does that mean

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes to the `while` loop in `main`: decrement `tries` each time through the loop and check whether the game has been won.

```
while (tries >=  0 && !hasWon()) {
    String wordguess = kb.next();
    char guess = wordguess.charAt(0);
    processGuess(guess, word, bool);
    printPattern(word, bool);
    --tries;
}
```

It might be useful to modify `processGuess` to return a boolean instead of an int, where the return value would be `true` if the guess was new and `false` if the user had already guessed that. Then you could mark it as a try only if it was a new guess:

```
while (tries >=  0 && !hasWon()) {
    String wordguess = kb.next();
    char guess = wordguess.charAt(0);
    if (processGuess(guess, word, bool)} {
        --tries;
    }
    printPattern(word, bool);
}
```